# JAX-WS response with holder<List<T>> with an object but with null attributes

Tags: list, soap, null, wsdl, jax-ws

i have a big problem calling a webService. When i did the import of the classes of the wsdl, i give this @WebService as a interface:

```
public void consultarProgramaCronicos(
        @WebParam(name = "consultarProgramaCronicos", targetNamespace = "") ConsultarProgramaCronicosVO consultarProgramaCronicos,
        @WebParam(name = "sip", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<String> sip,
        @WebParam(name = "programaCronico", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<List<ProgramaCronicoVO>> programaCronico,
        @WebParam(name = "marcaCronicidad", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<List<MarcaCronicidadVO>> marcaCronicidad)
        throws ConsultarProgramaCronicosFault;
```

So in my class, when i call this method i need to call it like this:

```
final Holder<String> sipHolder = new Holder<String>();
final Holder<List<ProgramaCronicoVO>> listProgramaCronico = new Holder<List<ProgramaCronicoVO>>();
final Holder<List<MarcaCronicidadVO>> listMarcaCronicidad = new Holder<List<MarcaCronicidadVO>>();
cronicos.consultarProgramaCronicos(cpc, sipHolder, listProgramaCronico, listMarcaCronicidad);
```

I pass an cpc object with the parameters i want, and i pass 3 holders for the answer.
The problem is i receive an object in the list  but the primitive parameters of the object is "null".

This is the xml i receive:

```
<soap:Body wsu:Id="id-1995630735" xmlns:wsu="">
<consultarProgramaCronicosResponse xmlns="">
  <sip>1703595</sip>
  <marcaCronicidad>
    <tipoMarca>CCC</tipoMarca>
    <resultado>624</resultado>
    <estadosalud>5</estadosalud>
    <gravedad>1</gravedad>
    <nivel>1</nivel>
    <descripcionNivel>Texto cualquiera.</descripcionNivel>
  </marcaCronicidad>
</consultarProgramaCronicosResponse></soap:Body>
```

In the "sip" holder i have the corrrect value. But In the List holder i have a list with one element of MarcaCronicidadV0, but all the string of this element are null.

Now, i show you a part of the .wsdl:

```
<xsd:complexType name="consultarProgramaCronicosResponse">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="sip" type="xs:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="programaCronico" type="tns:programaCronicoVO"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="marcaCronicidad" type="tns:marcaCronicidadVO"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="marcaCronicidadVO">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="tipoMarca" type="xs:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="resultado" type="xs:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="estadosalud" type="xs:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gravedad" type="xs:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="nivel" type="xs:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And this is the class MarcaCronicidadVO:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "marcaCronicidadVO", namespace = "", propOrder = { "tipoMarca",
        "resultado", "estadosalud", "gravedad", "nivel" })
public class MarcaCronicidadVO {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String tipoMarca;
    protected String resultado;
    protected String estadosalud;
    protected String gravedad;
    protected String nivel;

    //getters y setters here
```

And in the end the "main object":

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "consultarProgramaCronicosResponse", namespace = "", propOrder = { "sip", "programaCronico","marcaCronicidad" })
public class ConsultarProgramaCronicosResponse {

    protected String sip;
    protected List<ProgramaCronicoVO> programaCronico;
    protected List<MarcaCronicidadVO> marcaCronicidad;

public String getSip() {
        return sip;
    }
public void setSip(String value) {
        this.sip = value;
    }
public List<MarcaCronicidadVO> getMarcaCronicidad() {
        if (marcaCronicidad == null) {
            marcaCronicidad = new ArrayList<MarcaCronicidadVO>();
        }
        return this.marcaCronicidad;
    }
public List<ProgramaCronicoVO> getProgramaCronico() {
        if (programaCronico == null) {
            programaCronico = new ArrayList<ProgramaCronicoVO>();
        }
        return this.programaCronico;
    }
```

Why i dont have any error, and i recieve 3 correct holder, but in the holder list i have an element with attributes String with null value??????

Sorry by my english. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but my problem is solved adding this parameter in the package-info class:

"elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED"

At the beginning i had this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://myUrl....")
```

Now i put:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://myUrl....", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

And with this runs ok!
I hope to be helpful.